# Carbon - Checking when there is no record in the database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

So I'm trying to check if there is or isn't a record in the database for a session time. I'm using carbon.

This is my code

```
  {{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($data->counsellor_availabilities ? $data->counsellor_availabilities->event_time : "No Time")}}
```

Currently there is no time, so there is a nonobject error being thrown, so I tried the ternary operator. The error I'm getting is.

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (No Time) at position 0 (N): The timezone could not be found in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
{{ $data->counsellor_availabilities ? \Carbon\Carbon::parse($data->counsellor_availabilities->event_time) : 'No time' }}
```